# What are advantages of bundling Node.js applications?

Tags: node.js, bundling-and-minification

I'm wondering which improvement can bring bundling to Node.js project. Of course such tools like webpack or rollup can help to optimize codebase, but if project size doesn't matter, should I even care about bundling?

Comment: don't waste your time, use node 12... you'll get almost most of the latest javascript features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to write a library that working on both node.js and browser, or you want to support old node version, you should bundling it (ofcourse, include babel).

Otherwise, don't worry about it, just use newest node version and then you can use anything you want.

You can see list features that was supported by each node version [here](https://node.green/)